# importar uma tupla mongodb

Tags: mongodb

Olá, eu estou fazendo a importação de uma coleção de documentos do mongodb, estou importando de um arquivo csv, estou com problema na importação de pares chave:valor, o mongodb está reconhecendo tudo como string, exemplo:
Eu quero que o documento seja salvo assim na importação.

```html
"coordinates" : {
        "latitude" : -9.646375,
        "longitude" : -35.728146
    },
```

Mas está sendo salvo assim:

```html
"coordinates" : "{\"latitude\" :-9.739.990.639.836.790, \"longitude\" : -3.664.870.887.994.760}"
}
```

O arquivo csv está com o campo coordinates assim

```html
coordinates
{"latitude" :-9.262.132.106.882.630, "longitude" : -3.793.454.647.064.200}
```

Gostaria de ajuda para que eu consiga importar o documento e o banco reconheça este dicionário como realmente é, e não como uma string.

Agradeço a ajuda de todos!

Comment: Não entendi. Tu tem o arquivo, lê ele em algum lugar? Com alguma linguagem? Como tu tá importando no mongo?

Comment: É no shell do mongo, existe um arquivo que eu importo seus dados para o banco de dados mongo. Um desses dados é composto(coordinates{lat,long}) e eu não sei como faço para importar esse dado em conformidade com o banco de dados.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quando você tem um `csv`, a quebra da linha representa o valor para a chave da linha anterior, então:

```
coordinates
{"latitude" :-9.262.132.106.882.630, "longitude" : -3.793.454.647.064.200}
```

Significa que seu "titulo" seria: coordinates, mas seu valor é tudo isso:

```
{"latitude" :-9.262.132.106.882.630, "longitude" : -3.793.454.647.064.200}
```

Se tu quiser importar um arquivo direto no shell, poderia importar seu proprio .json, por exemplo, que ficaria certinho.

Supomos:

Conteudo do arquivo: `file.json`

```
{
  "Coordenadas": {
    "Latitude": 1231231,
    "Longitude": 212312312
  }
}
```

E a importação no shell:

```
mongoimport -d suaBase -c suaCollection --type json --file D:\file.json
```

E o conteúdo final na base:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59524d366f8cb1943dc17220"),
    "Coordenadas" : {
        "Latitude" : 1231231,
        "Longitude" : 212312312
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, obrigado, eu consegui resolver este problema de forma mais bruta, por conta da demanda que estava em cima para ser entregue, mas com seu conhecimento posso melhorar a tarefa, Valeu!

Comment: Obrigado Aline!